# Looping through an array of strings in Matlab

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, for-loop

I'm trying to just loop through some folders using a list of strings in Matlab and everything I've tried hasn't worked.

For instance, if I had three names, all I'd want is to loop through some folders like this:

```
names = ['Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry']

SourceDir = /path/to/my/files

for name = 1:length(names)

    mkdir SourceDir, "/things_belonging_to_", names(name), "/new_things"
    OutputDir = (SourceDir, "/things_belonging_to_", names(name), "/new_things")

    cd "/things_belonging_to_", names(name), "/oldthings"

    % do other stuff that will be dumped in OutputDir

end
```

I've tried using `{}` instead of `[]`, I tried to use `sprintf` and `fullfile`. All I want is a really boring for-loop and I cannot seem to find/understand the documentation that shows me how to use strings in the `mkdir` or `cd` command. I always end up with `string input not supported` or `Arguments must contain a character vector`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`names = ['Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry']` makes `names` a string rather than a string array. To use string array, make sure you have MATLAB 2016b+ where you can use double quotation mark:

```
names = ["Tom", "Dick", "Harry"]
```

Otherwise, use cell array:

```
names = {'Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry'}
```

And access the elements using curly bracket and index:

```
names{1} % Tom
names{2} % Dick
```

There are also a number of other mistakes in your code:

```
SourceDir = '/path/to/my/files'
mkdir([SourceDir, '/things_belonging_to_', char(names(name)), '/new_things'])
OutputDir = [SourceDir, '/things_belonging_to_', char(names(name)), '/new_things']

cd(['/things_belonging_to_', char(names(name)), '/oldthings'])
```

In MATLAB you can use square bracket `[]` to concatenate strings into one.

All in one:

```
names = {'Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry'};

SourceDir = '/path/to/my/files';

for name = 1:length(names)

    mkdir([SourceDir, '/things_belonging_to_', names{name}, '/new_things'])
    OutputDir = [SourceDir, '/things_belonging_to_', names{name}, '/new_things']

    cd(['/things_belonging_to_', names{name}, '/oldthings'])

    % do other stuff that will be dumped in OutputDir

end
```

---

Further readings:

[String array](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/string.html)

[Characters and Strings](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/characters-and-strings.html)

Comment: I appreciate your help but even using your example I have returned to my `Error using mkdir Arguments must contain a character vector.` error. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: @SolebaySharp my bad. you have to convert `names(name)` to char: `char(names(name))` or simply use cell array. I have updated my answer to reflect the change.

Comment: Thank you I have been working on this for some time.